# How to find the plane with given 2 vectors?

Tags: calculus, vectors

I am given vector $a=(2,-1,3)$ and vector $b=(3,0,-1)$. I need to find the equation of a plane which passes through this 2 vectors.

I tried finding the cross product and I get vector $(1, 11, 3)$. If this vector is normal to the plane then $$x+11y+3z+D=0$$ is the equation of the plane.

But how do we find $D$?

Comment: Two vectors give you a vector space (a direction). To get an affine space, you need a point that belongs to that space and a direction.

Comment: Also, it is the 10th time you post here, please remember to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Comment: I am still learning...

Comment: No worries at all. I did not mean it in a negative way :) It is just part of the rules of the site that make it easier for future readers to find relevant information.

Comment: Does the original problem you’re trying to solve say “passes through” or “contains?” (I suspect it’s really the latter.)

Comment: @ViktorDimitrioski Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint: }$
$$$$I assume you are to find the plane containing the $lines$ parallel to the vectors $\vec{a}=2i-j+3k$ and $\vec b=3i-k$. Without this assumption, the question cannot be solved beyond what you have already reached.
$$$$
Let $\vec{r}$ be the position vector of any point in the plane. let $\vec{p}$ be the position vector of the point of intersection of the two (non parallel) lines that have been given. 
$$$$
Clearly $\vec{r}-\vec{p}$ lies in the plane, hence it is perpendicular to the normal to the plane (given by the cross product of $2i-j+3k$ and $3i-k$)
. Hence, $$(\vec{r}-\vec{p}).\left((2i-j+3k) \times (3i-k)\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes you derivation by cross product is correct.

Without any other information, we assume that the plane is throught the origin thus $d=0$.

Otherwise, for the general case, we need an extra information on a point $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in$ plane or by the distance from the origin  in order to find $d$.

Comment: is there any way i can find point on this plane so I can find D?

Comment: @ViktorDimitrioski without any other information the plane is assumed to pass throught the origin, thus $d=0$.

Comment: @Ishan Why do you think it is wrong? with only 2 vectors we can only determine a plane throught the origin.

Comment: @gimusi I'm sorry, I was wrong . I had assumed the question to be slightly different, hence I thought you're answer wasn't correct. Sorry again.

Comment: @Ishan Never mind, You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough information to specify the exact value of D in your equation. I would leave the equation as$$ x+11y+3z+D=0$$ until a point on the plane is given.

At this point we have a family of parallel planes.